# Getting 400 Error for a POST Rest Service in Spring Boot

Tags: postman

**My payload is as follows:**

```
public class CriteriaVO implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4809182119185775529L;

    private final List<String> categories;
    
    private final List<String> subCategories;

    public CriteriaVO(List<String> categories, List<String> subCategories) {
        super();
        this.categories = categories;
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }

    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public List<String> getSubCategories() {
        return subCategories;
    }
    
}
```

**Below is my RestController class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("questions")
public class QuestionsController {
    
    @Autowired
    private QuestionDao questionDaoImpl;
    
    @GetMapping(path= "health", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String health() {
        return "Wish all good health!";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "findByCriteria", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, name = "findByCriteria")
    public List<Question> findByCriteria(@RequestBody CriteriaVO criteria) {
        System.out.println("test");
        List<Question> questions = this.questionDaoImpl.findByCriteria(criteria.getCategories(), criteria.getSubCategories());
        return questions;               
    }
    

    @PostMapping(path = "test", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, consumes=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, name = "test")
    public String test(@RequestBody String test) {
        System.out.println(test);
        return "returned " + test;              
    }

}
```

**I am using the following JSON to invoke the findbyCriteria method**

```
{"categories":["Observability"],"subCategories":["Tracing","General"]}
```

**Below is the curl command generated by Postman:**

```
curl --location 'localhost:8080/questions/findByCriteria' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data '

{"categories":["Observability"],"subCategories":["Tracing","General"]}'
```

**But I am getting 400 error. Not able to figure out the problem. The other 2 methods work fine.**

**Update 1:**
Below is the image of the response when used curl command
[image]

Below is the image of the response when used Postman
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the shell (like Windows Command Line versus Powershell versus Linux) it could be necessary to escape the quotes in the JSON string. Like:

```
'{\"categories\":[\"Observability\"],\"subCategories\":[\"Tracing\",\"General\"]}'
```

That's why a better option is to put your request in a text file and call curl with it. Like:

```
curl --location 'localhost:8080/questions/findByCriteria' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data @somefile.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was using the same escape characters as you suggested. However, the error seems to be something different. The service returns response from Window's command prompt but throws 400 when invoked from Postman. 

Please refer to the update above

Comment: Postman screenshot shows the call of find. It is not defined in RestController. There is only findbycriteria.